# Changing game mode in Tic Tac Toe [The Odin Project]

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener, tic-tac-toe

This is my first question here, so I apologize beforehand if I'm doing this wrong!

I'm learning to code with *The Odin Project*. So far, I've been doing every project without any major problems: some difficulty here and there, but after some thinking I was able to solve them successfully.

Currently, I'm at the *Tic Tac Toe* JavaScript project. I've already made the game work, implementing two game modes: **VS Player 2** and **VS CPU**. Both are first selected through an *HTML* welcome window I made in order to avoid using prompts, and both run without problems. However, whenever I try to change the game mode through buttons I placed in the interface, I fail and the mode keeps the same.

For example, if I want to change from **VS Player 2 mode** to **VS CPU mode**, the score resets and the player's names change, but the game keeps running in the **VS Player 2 mode**. There's no console error displayed, so I'm sure this is related either to scope or logic!

I've already tried many things, including generating the *HTML* welcome window with *JavaScript DOM* manipulation, but I'm not able to make it work. It's been two weeks since I faced this problem and I'm still hitting a brick wall!

Here's the part of the code that manages the mode selection:

```
const modeSelector = {
constants: [
    /* 0 */ modalOverlay = document.getElementById("modal-overlay"),
    /* 1 */ modalWindow = document.getElementById("modal-window"),
    /* 2 */ modalContent = document.getElementById("modal-content"),
    /* 3 */ gameButtons = document.getElementById("game-buttons"),
    /* 4 */ popUpVs = document.getElementById("popUpVs"),
    /* 5 */ popUpCpu = document.getElementById("popUpCpu"),     
    /* 6 */ vsPlayerTwo = document.getElementById("vsplayer2"),
    /* 7 */ vsCPU = document.getElementById("vsCPU"),
],
gameMode(mode) {
    if (mode === "") {
    } else if (mode === "vsPlayerTwoMode") {
        gameBoard.cleanBoard();
        p1 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
        p1.name = playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML;
        playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML = "0";
        p2 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
        p2.name = playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML;
        playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML = "0";
        movements.movement();
        rules.turnChanger();
    } else if (mode === "vsCPUMode") {
        gameBoard.cleanBoard();
        p1 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
        p1.name = playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML;
        playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML = "0";
        p2 = playerCreator.createPlayer();
        p2.name = "CPU"
        playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML = p2.name;
        playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML = "0";
        movements.vsCpuMovement();
        rules.turnChanger();
    }
},
reset() {
    gameBoard.cleanBoard();
    modeSelector.gameMode("");
    playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = "0";
    playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML = "0";
    playerCreator.scores[0].innerHTML = "0";
    playerCreator.scores[1].innerHTML = "0";
},    
popUpMode(mode) {
    if (mode === "popUpVsMode") {
        modeSelector.constants[2].innerHTML = "Insert Player 1 name";
    } else if (mode === "popUpCPUMode") {
        modeSelector.constants[2].innerHTML = "Insert Player name";
    }
    modeSelector.constants[2].style.marginLeft = "130px";
    modeSelector.constants[4].remove();
    modeSelector.constants[5].remove();
    let p1NameBar = document.createElement("input");
    p1NameBar.id = "p1NameBar";
    p1NameBar.maxLength = "6";
    modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p1NameBar);
    let p1NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
    p1NameOk.class = "popUpButton";
    p1NameOk.type = "button";
    p1NameOk.id = "popUpP1NameOk";
    p1NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
    modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p1NameOk);
    p1NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (mode === "popUpVsMode") {
            playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = p1NameBar.value;
            modeSelector.constants[2].innerHTML = "Insert Player 2 name";
            modeSelector.constants[2].style.marginLeft = "130px";
            p1NameBar.remove();
            p1NameOk.remove();
            let p2NameBar = document.createElement("input");
            p2NameBar.id = "p2NameBar";
            p2NameBar.maxLength = "6";
            modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p2NameBar);
            let p2NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
            p2NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
            p2NameOk.type = "button";
            p2NameOk.id = "popUpP2NameOk";
            p2NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
            modeSelector.constants[3].appendChild(p2NameOk);
            p2NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
                playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML= p2NameBar.value;
                document.body.removeChild(modalOverlay);
                modeSelector.gameMode("vsPlayerTwoMode");                    
            });
        } else if (mode === "popUpCPUMode") {
            playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = p1NameBar.value;
            document.body.removeChild(modalOverlay);
            modeSelector.gameMode("vsCPUMode");
        }
    });
},
inGameMode(mode) {
    modeSelector.reset()
    let inGameOverlay = document.createElement("div");
    inGameOverlay.id = "inGameOverlay";
    inGameOverlay.className = "modal-overlay";
    document.body.appendChild(inGameOverlay);
    let inGameWindow = document.createElement("div");
    inGameWindow.className = "modal-window";
    inGameWindow.id = "inGameWindow";
    inGameOverlay.appendChild(inGameWindow);
    let inGameTitleBar = document.createElement("div");
    inGameTitleBar.className = "modal-titlebar";
    inGameTitleBar.id = "inGameTitleBar";
    inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameTitleBar);
    let inGameTitle = document.createElement("span");
    inGameTitle.className = "modal-title";
    inGameTitle.id = "inGameTitle";
    if (mode === "VSP2") {
        inGameTitle.innerHTML = "VS Player 2 Mode";
        inGameTitle.style.marginLeft = "160px";
        inGameTitleBar.appendChild(inGameTitle);
        let inGameContent = document.createElement("div");
        inGameContent.className = "modal-content";
        inGameContent.id = "inGameContent";
        inGameContent.innerHTML = "Insert Player 1 name";
        inGameContent.style.marginLeft = "120px";
        inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameContent);
        let inGameButtons = document.createElement("div");
        inGameButtons.className = "modal-buttons";
        inGameButtons.id = "inGameButtons";
        inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameButtons);
        let inGameP1NameBar = document.createElement("input");
        inGameP1NameBar.id = "p1NameBar";
        inGameP1NameBar.maxLength = "6";
        inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameBar);
        let inGameP1NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
        inGameP1NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
        inGameP1NameOk.type = "button";
        inGameP1NameOk.id = "popUpP1NameOk";
        inGameP1NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
        inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameOk);
        inGameP1NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
            playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = inGameP1NameBar.value;
            inGameContent.innerHTML = "Insert Player 2 name";
            inGameContent.style.marginLeft = "130px";
            inGameP1NameBar.remove();
            inGameP1NameOk.remove();
            let inGameP2NameBar = document.createElement("input");
            inGameP2NameBar.id = "p2NameBar";
            inGameP2NameBar.maxLength = "6";
            inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP2NameBar);
            let inGameP2NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
            inGameP2NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
            inGameP2NameOk.type = "button";
            inGameP2NameOk.id = "popUpP2NameOk";
            inGameP2NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
            inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP2NameOk);
            inGameP2NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
                playerCreator.names[1].innerHTML= inGameP2NameBar.value;
                document.body.removeChild(inGameOverlay);
                modeSelector.gameMode("vsPlayerTwoMode");
            })
        });
    } else if (mode === "VSCPU") {
        inGameTitle.innerHTML = "VS CPU Mode";
        inGameTitle.style.marginLeft = "210px";
        inGameTitleBar.appendChild(inGameTitle);
        let inGameContent = document.createElement("div");
        inGameContent.className = "modal-content";
        inGameContent.id = "inGameContent";
        inGameContent.innerHTML = "Insert Player 1 name";
        inGameContent.style.marginLeft = "120px";
        inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameContent);
        let inGameButtons = document.createElement("div");
        inGameButtons.className = "modal-buttons";
        inGameButtons.id = "inGameButtons";
        inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameButtons);
        let inGameP1NameBar = document.createElement("input");
        inGameP1NameBar.id = "p1NameBar";
        inGameP1NameBar.maxLength = "6";
        inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameBar);
        let inGameP1NameOk = document.createElement("h2");
        inGameP1NameOk.className = "popUpButton";
        inGameP1NameOk.type = "button";
        inGameP1NameOk.id = "popUpP1NameOk";
        inGameP1NameOk.innerHTML = "OK";
        inGameButtons.appendChild(inGameP1NameOk);
        inGameP1NameOk.addEventListener("click", () => {
            playerCreator.names[0].innerHTML = inGameP1NameBar.value;
            document.body.removeChild(inGameOverlay);
            modeSelector.gameMode("vsCPUMode");
        });    
    }
    let inGameInfo = document.createElement("div");
    inGameInfo.id = "modal-info";
    inGameInfo.innerHTML = "You can reset the game mode during the match by clicking on any of the buttons to the right";
    inGameWindow.appendChild(inGameInfo);
},
```

};

There's also some **addEventListeners** for "click" that implement the above code in the different buttons, but I didn't want to add more code so I'm also sharing the full thing over at *GitHub*:

https://github.com/roznerx/tic_tac_toe

Thanks in advance and, again, sorry if I'm asking this the wrong way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we first start in `vsPlayerTwoMode` mode, then `movements.movement()` adds an event listener to each box on the board. When a box is clicked, it checks to see if its empty and depending on whose turn it is (based on the values of `playerCreator.turns[0]` and `playerCreator.turns[1]`), will set `gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML` to either `X` or `O`.

Now let's switch to the `vsCPUMode` mode. Each box on the board now has the original event listener attached to it (from `movements.movement()`), and the new event listener from `movements.vsCpuMovement()`. When a box is clicked, it will first evaluate the logic in the above paragraph (as defined in the `movements.movement()` event listener), and then the logic in the `movements.vsCpuMovement()` function (notably, check to see if `gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML == ""`).

However, since the `movements.movement()` event is called before the `movements.vsCpuMovement()` event, then `gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML` is going to be set to either `X` or `O` depending on the previous values of `playerCreator.turns[0]` and `playerCreator.turns[1]`. Then, the `movements.vsCpuMovement()` checks to see if `gameBoard.board[i].innerHTML` is an empty string, and it won't be, so the function returns.

**Importantly**, when the mode is `vsCPUMode` to start, the `movements.movement()` event listener is never registered, so it doesn't matter what the values of `playerCreator.turns[0]` or `playerCreator.turns[1]` are.

How do we fix it? One option would be to reset the values of `playerCreator.turns[...]` so that when the `movements.movement()` event is called, it simply ignores the logic that depends on those values (which is *somewhat equivalent* to starting the game in mode `vsCPUMode`). In other words, add these two lines after [line 215](https://github.com/roznerx/tic_tac_toe/blob/211b0909dbddb36893e385f92f1ea6c8868c82b2/tictactoe.js#L215):

```
playerCreator.turns[0] = ""
playerCreator.turns[1] = ""
```

Is there a better way to solve the problem? You bet! I would recommend posting your code over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and asking people for suggestions. If you are only interested in solving this immediate problem, I would keep track of all the event listeners you add to the gameboard boxes, and if you change the modes, [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) any existing listeners before adding newer ones.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for such a detailed and kind answer!!!

I cannot believe it had to do with the turn changing system! Guess I was so obfuscated and frustrated with modeSelector that I forsake that part of the code. 

Honestly, I want to solve this quick in order to keep advancing and learning new things, but I know I should slow down and try to clean and perfect the code as much as possible. 

I'm not completely sold on the idea of storing every method inside objects, but that's what The Odin Project suggests! I'll post on Code Review ASAP. Again, THANK YOU!!!